# Generative AI Use Case for Search Domain

Tags: search

I am trying to think and research for use cases that can beneficial search experience using Generative AI. There are two things,

- The final search results that can be more relevant and personalised per user. This would take time and more effort - in terms the backend search service to change/upgrade etc.
- The more I am trying to focus how can generative ai be leveraged and provide to benefits on the client side while user is actually search. One thought I had:
  *used to generate new keywords and topics that can be used to improve the search engine's coverage of a particular topic. This can help to provide more relevant results to users.*

I wanted to understand what other use case have you witnessed/seem where generative ai can really helpful while user is actually searching (on the client side experience)

Comment: It may be a bit simplistic, but the biggest **problem** I find with search results is wordiness, not being able to understand what I am about to click on. Constantly I use a site like these guides here https://www.plainenglish.co.uk/free-guides.html and feed them into LLM's to reword stuff and it works perfectly. So you have more relevant results, but can they be understood by the user? (I didn't write this as a question btw as I don't think it fully answers your question)

Comment: Thanks @jamiecropley

Comment: Please checkout https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/157/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One use case which pops into my mind is that of Query Expansion. Gen AI can analyze user queries and expand them with synonyms, or contextually relevant keywords, which allows for more comprehensive search results and increased coverage of the desired topics.

Another one which might be useful is the Auto-tagging and Categorization. It becomes easier for search engines to organize and present results in a structured manner when content is tagged and categorized.

Use case which might be difficult to implement will be like Multilingual Search.